# How can I connect QtcpSockets to about 100 servers without a UI hang?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcpsocket

How can I connect QtcpSockets to about 100 servers without a UI hang?

When I create 100 QTcpSockets to connect to each server and call the connectToHost() function, the QDialog stuck. Is there a way to run the connectToHost() part as a background job?

As a result, all connections are made, but while trying to connect (call connectToHost() the UI is in 'No Response' state.

```cpp
// onConnectToICPMC is the slot function connected to the dialog button pressed signal
void WidgetUploadFile::onConnectToICPMC()
{
    // m_tcpClients is a QVector containing a custm QObject Class that manages QTcpSocket
    for(int i = 0; i < m_tcpClients.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(m_tcpClients.at(i)->state() != QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
        {
            m_tcpClients.at(i)->connectToServer(); // Call the connectToHost() function of QTcpSocket.
        }
        emit sendConnProgBarUpdate(i+1);
        emit sendCurrentSockLog(m_tcpClients.at(i)->ipAddress(), m_tcpClients.at(i)->state());
    }
}
```

A dialog that hangs while each QTcpSocket connects to the server.:
[image: A dialog that hangs while each QTcpSocket connects to the server.]

After all QTcpSockets try to connect to the server:
[image: After all QTcpSockets try to connect to the server]

Comment: The most simple solution might be to embed a [QApplication::processEvents()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) in the loop. This will process the queued events in each iteration, so that it hangs always for one connection attempt only. If this is not yet sufficient then you have to consider multi-threading but that probably will require more effort.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks for the reply. When I tried connectToHost() from another thread, 'When Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread' debug message is generated, so I coded as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time-consuming tasks should not be run on the main thread. In that case there are 2 strategies:

- Use of threads.
- Divide into subtasks and execute in parts every T seconds.

In this case I think the second option is the best using [`QTimeLine`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimeline.html).

***.h**

```cpp
private:
   void handleFrameChanged(int i);
   QTimeLine timeLine;
```

***.cpp**

```cpp
{
    // constructor
    timeLine.setRange(0, m_tcpClients.size()-1);
    connect(&timeLine, &QTimeLine::frameChanged, this, &WidgetUploadFile::handleFrameChanged);
}

void WidgetUploadFile::onConnectToICPMC()
{
    timeLine.start();
}

void WidgetUploadFile::handleFrameChanged(int i){
    auto client = m_tcpClients.at(i);
    if(client->state() != QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState){
        client->connectToServer();
    }       
    emit sendConnProgBarUpdate(i + 1);
    emit sendConnProgBarUpdate(client->ipAddress(), client->state());
}
```

Comment: @eyllansec Implemented using QTimer referring to how to use your QTimeLine. No more UI hangs. Thank you very much for your idea!